# Pandas dataframe significant performance enhancement when adding a column after reset_index(drop=True)

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

I am surprised to find that adding a column to dataframe so time consuming, and after doing a reset_index can improve the performance to such a great deal. Below is the code snippet that showing the performance difference.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(size=(1000, 3)))
sub_df = df.loc[30:32, :]
sub_df_1 = sub_df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Now I am going to add a new column on `sub_df` and `sub_df_1` (which is reset_index version of sub_df)

```
%timeit sub_df[3] = 1
201 ms ± 3.76 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit sub_df_1[3] = 1
139 µs ± 8.86 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

The performance improvement is larger than 1000 times! And it is also worth noting that without reset_index, it will take 0.2 seconds to add a column to a three-row dataframe...

Is there any reason for the difference of performance? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't observe that (both ops are comparable microseconds on my machine)

Comment: A few comments however: this kind of comparison can fail when scaling up in many ways.  At only a few rows, it's almost certainly dominated by overhead operation, like provisioning memory, creating a copy as needed, or other "under the hood" bits.  These will be a small fraction of the cost as your data grows.  Maybe more importantly, it's not clear that this is an apples to apples comparison, as your sub_dfs are not "new" objects but probably contain references to the existing

Comment: I also feel that the performance difference could be result from sub_dfs are a reference of the original df. But that is actually what I want to dig more - why such reference can result in such a big overhead? And for what it might worth, this behavior is observable on my Windows10 machine with python 3.6, pandas version as 0.22.0.